# Binary Search in C

Tags: algorithm, c, binary-search

The standard C library function `bsearch` wasn't giving me correct results, apparently. So I decided to implement a binary searching function in place of it. It functions correctly up till now, though I haven't tested it thoroughly.

```
void * bsearch2(const void * base, const void * elem, const size_t nmemb, const size_t size, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *))
{
    /* Looks for elem in array. If found returns its address, else returns NULL
    Using the Binary Searching Algorithm, Assuming array to be sorted. */
    if (nmemb == 0) return NULL;

    size_t length = nmemb;
    int result;
    void * check;

    while (length > 0) {
        length = (length == 1) ? 0 : (size_t) length / 2;
        check = (void *)(base + (size * length));
        /* negative: element is greater, positive: element is smaller, zero: element is equal */
        result = compar(check, elem);
        if (result == 0)
            return check;
        if (result < 0) /* the element is in the second half */
            base = check;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

Are there any drawbacks in this function that I might be overlooking ?

Comment: It seems exactly the same as the standard `bsearch`, with the exception that you have inverted the order of parameters in the predicate function. The standard one uses `comp(key,item)`, yours is `comp(item,key)`.

Comment: @glampert: Really ? Well that's great, because I wanted to see the original `bsearch` source code and I couldn't find it in glibc on [ftp.gnu.org](ftp://ftp.gnu.org) ..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be interesting to know why the `bsearch()` library function does not
work for you, but here are some remarks to your code:

- The initial check

  ```
  if (nmemb == 0) return NULL;
  ```

  is not really necessary. If `nmemb` is zero then the following loop will not
  execute at all, and the outcome is the same.
- The cast to `size_t` in

  ```
  length = (length == 1) ? 0 : (size_t) length / 2;
  ```

  has no effect, and the conditional expression is not needed either, because `1/2`
  evaluates to zero. So this can be simplified to

  ```
  length = length / 2;
  ```
- Arithmetic with a pointer to `void` as in

  ```
   check = (void *)(base + (size * length));
  ```

  is a [GNU extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Pointer-Arith.html) and not portable. You should replace it by

  ```
   check = (void *)((char *)base + (size * length));
  ```
- In the case `result < 0` you continue searching in the second half of the array
  *including* the element that was just tested. And this is actually an *error*,
  your function does not find the last element of an array with an odd number
  of elements. Moving `base` "one to the right"

  ```
  if (result < 0) { /* the element is in the second half */
      base = (void *)((char *)check + size);
  }
  ```

  fixes the problem.